# How do I use v-on="$listeners" except for @click?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `Button.vue` looks like this. I'm using `v-on="$listeners"` to pass all listeners to `<a>`.

```html
<template>
    <a
        v-bind="$attrs"
        v-on="$listeners"
        class="Button"
        href="javascript: void(0)"
        :class="{ disabled }"
        @click="onClick()"
    >
        <slot></slot>
    </a>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            disabled: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            }
        },
        methods: {
            onClick() {
                if (!this.disabled) {
                    this.$emit('click');
                }
            }
        },
    };
</script>
```

But I need a custom check before propagating the `@click` event, so I also defined `@click`.
But when I define both `v-on="$listeners"` and `@click="onClick()"` at the same time, the `onClickDelete` function get called twice. I also tried `@click.prevent`, but still doesn't work.

```html
<Button @click="onClickDelete">Delete</Button>
```

Is there a way I can define `v-on="$listeners"` for all the events except `@click`?

Here's the [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-albattani-43elt?file=/src/App.vue).

Comment: I came across this article in the Vue docs and remembered this question, so I came back here to leave the link in case it's helpful for anyone.

https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could create a copy of `$listeners` (by spreading it into a new object), and overwrite `click`:

```html
<a v-on="{ ...$listeners, click: () => {} }">
```

[demo 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/excluding-click-listener-from-listeners-forked-c9zl9?file=/src/components/Button.vue:36-82)

Or create a [computed prop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) that excludes any `click` event handler:

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    myListeners() {
      const { click, ...listeners } = this.$listeners // exclude `click`-listener
      return listeners
    },
  },
}
```

Then bind that prop to `v-on` in place of `$listeners`:

```html
<a v-on="myListeners">
```

[demo 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/excluding-click-listener-from-listeners-forked-po2bc?file=/src/components/Button.vue:308-428)